# Rails Button to Update Attribute Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link that looks like this in the object's show view:

```
<%= link_to "Approve", object_path(@object, status: true), method: :put, confirm: "Are you sure?", class: 'button' %>
```

The update action in the controller is standard and the object's regular edit form works just fine. But for some reason, this link isn't updating the boolean field to true...

Is there something that I did wrong with this link?

EDIT: Update Section of Controller

```
def update
  @object = Object.find_by_certain_field(params[:id])
  if @object.update_attributes(params[:object])
    flash[:success] = "Object Updated"
    redirect_to @object
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Posting the controller code might help. But without it, I'll hazard a guess that you are specifically setting the boolean field to true in the update action?

Comment: I added the controller's code to the question. I just use the `update_attributes` to set things that are posted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object_path(@object, status: true)` causes `params[:status]` to be true and not `params[:object][:status]` as you wish, thus not updating the object with `@object.update_attributes(params[:object])`

If you want to keep using the current code pattern just add

```
parmas[:object] ||= {} 
params[:object][:status] = params[:status] if params[:status]
```

before

```
if @object.update_attributes(params[:object])
```

and everything should be fine.

Otherwise I'd avise you to make a form for this update call:

```
<% form_for @object, :method => :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :status, :value => true %>
  <%= f.submit "Approve" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried putting this and it still didn't work: `<%= form_for @object, method: :put do |f| %> <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: true %> <%= f.submit "Approve" %> <% end %>`

Comment: And in the source, it has `<input id="object_status" name="object[status]" type="hidden" value="true" />` as well as `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/object/1" class="edit_object" id="edit_object_1" method="post">`

Comment: Can you please paste here the log of the rails server which receives this request? Also please add ! on the update_attributes method as in:
`if @object.update_attributes!(params[:object])`. This way if the object is not saved due to validation an error will be raise and it will be logged.

Comment: Upon looking at the log for the 1,000,000th time, I found a line that I somehow missed before. I had an authorization `before_filter` that limited my current_user's ability to do an update. I removed that and how it works... I'll mark yours the answer since it led me to the solution though! Thanks!!

Comment: And without switching it to the form (or adding the other params) it would have still thrown an error :)